# How to prove the convergence of the series $\sum\frac{(3n+2)^n}{3n^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove the convergence of this series:

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n+2)^n}{3n^{2n}}$$

I've tried using Cauchy's criterion and ended up with a limit of $1$, but I already know it does converge.

How am I suppose to prove it? Note that I've also tried the integral test and was not able to solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [root test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/RootTest.aspx) applies nicely here. Taking $\displaystyle a_n=\left(\frac{3\,n+2}{n^2}\right)^n$ gives 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3\,n+2}{n^2} =0<1
$$
This proves that $\sum a_n$ converges so your series $\frac{1}{3}\sum a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 5):

**hint**: $\dfrac{(3n+2)^n}{n^{2n}} = \left(\dfrac{3n+2}{n^2}\right)^n< \left(\dfrac{4}{n}\right)^n< \dfrac{16}{n^2}$

Comment: Much the same as my thoughts. I'd add that for $n>8$ in the above, the term is $<1/2^n$ so we can not just prove convergence but quickly get a bound on the sum.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use the $n$th root test.
$$
\left|\frac{(3n+2)^n}{3n^{2n}}\right|^{1/n} = \frac{3n+2}{3^{1/n}n^2} \to 0.
$$
Since $0<1$, the series converges absolutely.